# When clicking on the window, the event does not work in electron.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I need to create an application using the electron.js framework, create a window that can be moved by drag-and-drop, and also a method should be called when clicked

when clicking on my window, the event does not work.
the fact is that in styles, in order for my window to be able to move, I use the following:

```
html {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

works correctly on MacOS.
For some reason, it happens in Windows that the layout shifts. It is because of this style that the click event does not work.

I'm attaching screenshots for clarity:
[With styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxhdj.jpg)
[Without styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTAyX.jpg)

How can this problem be bypassed? Perhaps there is another way to force the window to move that won't prevent the event from working correctly?

I will be grateful for your help!

---

HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <img id="duck" src="assets/ducks/duck.png">
    <audio id="krik" preload="auto" src="assets/krik.mp3"></audio>
    <div id="callout">Hello!</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
*{
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select:none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
#duck {
  position: relative;
  height: 9.5rem;
  transition: all ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  animation: rubber-ducky infinite linear;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}
}
```

script.js

```
    let duck = document.getElementById('duck')
    duck.addEventListener('click', () => {
        audio.play();
    })
```

index.js

```
const createDuckWindow = () => {
    duckWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        frame: 0,
        hasShadow: false,
        transparent: true,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0)",
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        resizable: false, //set false
        width: 300, //300
        height: 200,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        minimizable: false,
        webPreferences: {
            backgroundThrottling: false,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        }
    })
    duckWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, "screen-saver");
    duckWindow.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true, {visibleOnFullScreen: true});
    duckWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
};
```

In the end, I want this simple window, with transparent background, which user can drag on desktop screen and when user click on picture, the duck will be make some sound.
[My application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At57s.png)

Comment: Just to clarify, is the drag region your whole `html` tag? This would not be very user friendly. A drag region would normally be allocated to a particular element if you are not showing the native window title bar. Additionally, what do you require your `click` event listener to be attached to? The duck or the `html` tag?

Comment: @midnight-coding i have a small window and i need to move it in the desktop area when i click anywhere on the window. so drag region - whole html tag

Comment: Is this a frameless window, a window without a title bar or a modal? Can you add your window (html) code and CSS code to your question as well?

Comment: @midnight-coding yes. I added index.js, index.html and css code into a question

Comment: Can you add you `onClick` code to your question as well, just so I know what element you are listening on. So, just to confirm, `click and hold` will move the duck around your screen(s). `Click` will make it quack (or something similar). Correct?

Comment: @midnight-coding click and hold will move the duck around your screen(s) works with css style, but only in MacOS, in Windows it doesn't work:
```
html {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

Comment: After some testing and reading, I don't think you can use `-webkit-app-region: drag;` on the `html` element and expect `#duck` to be clickable. A workaround will need to be implemented such as: 1. Click makes the duck quack. 2. Click and drag sends render mouse coordinates back for main process to move the window; The trick will be ensuring you don't get any stuttering of the moving window. What do you think?